# htaccess - redirect old domain to new with exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess - redirect old domain to new with exception

I have an old domain: [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com), with URL files: 1.php,2.php and 3.php
I want to redirect [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) to [www.newdomain.com](http://www.newdomain.com), but with the exception that 3.php should be automatically redirected/renamed to 4.php after the redirection, i.e.:

```
www.olddomain.com/3.php => www.newdomain.com/4.php
```

The rest should be the same:

```
www.olddomain.com/1.php => www.newdomain.com/1.php
www.olddomain.com/2.php => www.newdomain.com/2.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
Redirect /3.php /4.php[N]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Of course it doesn't work the way I want it, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/3\.php [NC] #usually use NC if using Windows
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/4.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/3\.php [NC] #usually use NC if using Windows
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#or if it adds two slashes use https://www.newdomain.com$1
```

Comment: @anubhava, I just tested it. Nope, it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work, still redirects to www.newdomain.com/3.php and not www.newdomain.com/4.php

Comment: @cmpt my first one?

Comment: still doesn't work, https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/4.php [R=301,L]

This rule was not met.

Comment: @cmpt I forgot that REQUEST_URI sometimes includes slashes? Oh god

Comment: @cmpt https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=28faa02f-10ed-4de5-9864-b4becfa0674e

Comment: Thank you now it works, thank you so much, you are the star!!!

Comment: Good answer @Exampleperson ++ .

Answer (score 2):

Have specific redirect before generic redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

# redirect 3.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^3\.php$ https://www.newdomain.com/4.php [L,NC,R=301]

# redirect everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: @cmpt: Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test this.